# Adding two numbers in assembly language

Tags: assembly, risc

What I am attempting is to compare 2 numbers in assembly language and display the largest of the two numbers, as shown in the pseudo code below.

I am using this website here to do this http://www.peterhigginson.co.uk/RISC/

Here is what I am came up with: 

    `INP R0,2
    INP R1,2
    CMP R0,R1
    BGT OUT R0,4
    BLT OUT R1,4`

However I am getting the error 'bad parameter at line 3 BGT'.
I am not sure why I am getting this however I suspect it may be something to do either with indentations or not including a loop or something.

Any help on how to solve this would be much appreciated.
Here is the instruction set if anyone is interested. http://www.peterhigginson.co.uk/RISC/instruction_set.pdf

Comment: Branches require a label as target (in your simulator you might only be allowed to use numerical addresses though).

Comment: @old_timer the instruction set is based on the ARM processor, new and thought some people over there could help me

Comment: @LewisWatkins Please only tag [arm] when your question is about ARM assembly. Something that is merely inspired by ARM should not be tagged as ARM as that is misleading.

Comment: inspired by arm perhaps but not arm.

Comment: sounds like you simply have a syntax error, look at other examples or the documentation to find the syntax for conditional branches.  from links you sent us you have extra stuff on the line.

Comment: alright cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

here's my approach:

```
        INP R0,2
        INP R1,2
        CMP R0,R1
        BGT g1
        OUT R1,4
        HLT
g1:     OUT R0,4
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
        INP R0,2
        INP R1,2
    l1:     CMP R0,R1
        BGT g1
        BLT g2
        BEQ g2
    g1: OUT R0,4
    g2: OUT R1,4
```

Comment: in the end, you'll always have out'ed R1. Add some "HLT" after OUTing. Also 2 of the branches aren't really needed, if you order the OUTs right